# Graphic artefacts on the screen

Tags: graphics, laptop, intel-graphics, hardware

I am running on a relatively old laptop, HP Compaq Presario CQ61 303sv, with relatively old hardware. Recently, the blurs and defects in the screenshot below started to appear in all the Ubuntu distributions I install. The screen becomes so blurred that it makes text impossible to read.

**Screenshot**: [image]
*notice the blurs and defects on center of screen, also the black dotted line on the right side*

Does anybody know why this is happening, and how it can be fixed?

The hardware I'm running is: Inte Core2Duo T6600, 3GB RAM, Intel GMA4500 MHD graphics.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### Buy a new laptop!

This strongly looks like your graphics chip is dying. My last laptop died because of the same problem. It will become worse the longer you keep it like this and the hotter the chip gets. If you also see an increase of the artefacts when the laptop heats up, it's a pretty sure thing. Also the fact that this started suddenly and on all installed systems supports the theory.

Maybe it could be possible to disassemble the laptop and change the graphics card, but without looking it up, it sounds more like an integrated chip, maybe even included in the CPU itself, so it is probably impossible to swap that.

I am sorry for you, but as you're saying it was an old laptop, I guess and hope it does not hurt too much...

Comment: As you're a reputation 11 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Earlier I had a similar problem. Overheating and dying GPU.